# Why do we frequently have to re-start the default web site to prevent errors 500 after a page edit?

Tags: 500-error, iis-8.5

We make frequent changes to web pages in virtual directories on our IIS 8.5 site. Many times after editing, the server responds with 'Error 500'. To resolve this, we restart the entire 'Default web site'. Is there a fix for this or are we doing something wrong?

UPDATE: Here is the resolution in case anyone else experiences the issue: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3007507

Comment: [Cargo Cult Systems Administration](http://blog.lastinfirstout.net/2009/11/cargo-cult-system-administration.html). **Treating symptoms, not causes**. A reboot will not ***solve*** your problem. It may make the problem go away for a while, but your problem still exists. You've addressed the symptom of the problem (memory fragmentation, for example), not the cause of the problem (a memory leak, for example).`

Comment: @HopelessN00b:  I appreciate your candor. I realize that I want to treat the cause so I came here and asked for help. Sorry to have disturbed you.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what kind of changed are you doing to the web pages and the logs are missing too from the question.

Answer (score 8):

You need to determine the reason for the 500 error. It's usual to look in your logs for more detail and work out from there.

---

You should also take a look at the excellent answer to [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/a/646876/9517) which gives sound advice on diagnosing issues.