# Cannot ping / ssh server after installing VirtualBox on CentOs 6.6

Tags: centos, ssh, ping

Our server was running fine this morning. I installed VirtualBox and rebooted the server. Since rebooting the server I do not recieve a response when pinging the IP address and I cannot connect through SSH anymore. I have access through KVM.

Does anybody know how I might begin to troubleshoot this? I am posting the process I went through to install VirtualBox incase there was some part of the process that has caused me an issue.

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/rhel/virtualbox.repo
yum update
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install VirtualBox-4.3
service vboxdrv setup
usermod -a -G vboxusers root
VirtualBox
```

I then connected to the server to set up a virtual machine and created a new virtual Windows 7 machine

```
ssh -X root@xxxxxxx
VirtualBox
```

I then rebooted the server and now I no longer recieve a response to my ping requests and I am unable to ssh to the server. I have KVM access.

Does anybody know what I may have done? I have done multiple reboots in the past with no issue so I assume the issue is something to do with VirtualBox.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anybody know how I might begin to troubleshoot this?

You know, the usual stuff from the sysadmin kitbag

Use your console access to

- check your logs and take appropriate action.
- check you have correctly configured network interfaces
- check your firewall.
- check that sshd is running
- check your change/config management system for other recent stuff
- ...

You may also find the [method here](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876) useful

Comment: http://www.freesound.org/people/Benboncan/sounds/73581/

Comment: You should take this as an opportunity to educate yourself. Reinstalling really isn't a good option.

Comment: I'm giving it a good go before I give up and reinstall. There really is too much to lose for me to reinstall now anyway.

I am going to take a look and see if sshd is running and configured correctly. The firewall settings are correct so I will take it step by step!

Comment: Yaay Iain, +1 from me.  Though as a trombonist with an aversion to flash, I can't say I appreciate the link above.

Comment: Is that better @MadHatter ?

Comment: Infinitely slightly so, yes.  Thanks.  I'm going off to do some practice.

Comment: Looks like I might be having some trouble with the network setup. Seems that something I have done has wiped /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/

Comment: Thank you for your help Iain. I have figured the issue out (or at least a resolution!) and have learnt a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Something during the VirtualBox setup had changed my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts and stopped the nameservers setting correctly.

To resolve this I turned off Network Manager

```
/etc/init.d/NetworkManager stop
/sbin/chkconfig NetworkManager off
```

Added

```
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
```

to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and manually edited /etc/resolv.conf with vi to the correct nameservers. Rebooted the server and issue seems to have gone away!