# Analyzing server performance

Tags: linux, performance, vps, performance-monitoring, performance-tuning

We have recently finished work on one ecommerce site which is built on opencart 2.x and site has around 1k products. The site is currently running on VPS server.

For some days we are facing some strange problem in the website. Sometimes some features are not working as well as sometimes errors are came and after some time they are not there, so it is very difficult to debug the whole system. It works fine sometime and sometimes the same code doesn't work.

We are not able to made any conclusion or find the cause of the problem.
We think it can be the server issue because on test version website which is run on another server is working properly.

It may be because of server traffic, some time scripts execute properly and sometime because of load on the server it does not.

If there is something problem in script it should be persistence, so I need a  technique to debug this kinds of problem.

Comment: Please see: http://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites

Answer (score 2):

The technique you want is called [scientific method](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876). With scientific method and some monitoring tools, you can diagnose the issue and take corrective action.