# Large CPU spike for proc (www-data)

Tags: monitoring, cpu-usage

I am trying to understand what is causing these routine high CPU loads on my server.

The server is using serverpilot on a small Digital Ocean Droplet which comfortable runs a few wordpress sites with very low traffic. Over the last two weeks I have seen (at the same time on a Friday) a process that triggers the following New Relic Alerts for CPU > 80%.

[image: New Relic Data]

[image: New Relic Data 2]

I am very concerned that this is a malicious PHP script that is sending mail or something similarly annoying. How can I narrow down what is causing the issue and prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

You (or someone on your behalf) will need to use [Scientific Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) or similar  to determine the cause.

You are already partly on your way in as much as you have defined the problem

> A large CPU spike

and have some data to work with. You will need to review the data you have. Analyse your logs and if necessary gather more data and analyse it.

[Being structured and methodical is the only way forward in a situation like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876).