# How do I diagnose non-working Netatalk on Centos?

Tags: centos7, apple, netatalk

Our Centos 7.1.503 server, running Netatalk recently ran to full disk capacity and our macs couldn't save files.  I rebooted it and removed some (non-system) files but now the Netatalk share isn't available on the network.  What's the procedure for diagnosing this problem and fixing it?

To complicate matters we recently moved premises and changed routers, although the server has been working in the new environment so I doubt this is an issue; although it's conceivable it's changed IP addresses I guess.

The server appears as "localhost" on the network and it appears to be pingable from the network, on the IP address it claims to be using.  But clicking on localhost and trying to connect doesn't reveal any of the mounted volumes.  Selecting "connect As..." gives an error; "the server does not appear to be available - check the server name and IP address."

The server has Internet and network access.

We have less secure authentication enabled on the clients.  The volumes are mounted and browsable from within the server console.

```
systemctl-list-unit-files -t service
```

reveals avahi and netatalk are running

Any ideas what has broken, or steps to proceed with a diagnosis?  What services need to be running for starters, and where do I check which volumes are shared on the network?

I also vaguely remember linking Netatalk to a certain Ethernet adapter; perhaps this has changed during the move?

Answer (score 2):

The term `localhost` has a special meaning ... it is the IPv4 loopback address 127.0.0.1 and it is not accessible outside the 'local' machine. If for example you are trying to connect from a Mac to the CentOS server and you see localhost on the Mac, it will try to connect to the Mac, not the CentOS server.

Beyond that you (or someone on your behalf) will need to use [Scientific Method](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876) to diagnose your issue.

Comment: It's also the name of this server on our network!  It works again now. Sadly I just tinkered with the Ethernet settings so I'll never know what fixed it! I think Netatalk was only available on a certain adapter. I can see why you would say that but our macs have connected to "Localhost" successfully for the past 5 years.