# Diagnosing Linux OOM Logs

Tags: linux, php, lamp

Repeatedly facing mysqld out of memory. Lots of PHP processes spawned, taking up all the swap.

```
[562074.326710] mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
[562074.329646] mysqld cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[562074.330882] Pid: 21351, comm: mysqld Not tainted 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1
[562074.333171] Call Trace:
[562074.334870]  [] ? dump_header+0x90/0x1b0
[562074.336812]  [] ? security_real_capable_noaudit+0x3c/0x70
[562074.338692]  [] ? oom_kill_process+0x82/0x2a0
[562074.340270]  [] ? select_bad_process+0xe1/0x120
[562074.341582]  [] ? out_of_memory+0x220/0x3c0
[562074.343229]  [] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x93c/0x950
[562074.344930]  [] ? ext4_get_block+0x0/0x120 [ext4]
[562074.346436]  [] ? alloc_pages_current+0xaa/0x110
[562074.347604]  [] ? __page_cache_alloc+0x87/0x90
[562074.348889]  [] ? find_get_page+0x1e/0xa0
[562074.350660]  [] ? filemap_fault+0x1a7/0x500
[562074.352207]  [] ? __do_fault+0x54/0x530
[562074.353872]  [] ? handle_pte_fault+0xf7/0xb20
[562074.355966]  [] ? rwsem_down_failed_common+0x95/0x1d0
[562074.357531]  [] ? rwsem_down_read_failed+0x26/0x30
[562074.359503]  [] ? handle_mm_fault+0x299/0x3d0
[562074.361105]  [] ? call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[562074.362522]  [] ? __do_page_fault+0x146/0x500
[562074.364590]  [] ? lock_sock_nested+0xac/0xc0
[562074.387996]  [] ? _spin_unlock_bh+0x1b/0x20
[562074.389187]  [] ? pvclock_clocksource_read+0x58/0xd0
[562074.390457]  [] ? kvm_clock_read+0x1c/0x20
[562074.391586]  [] ? kvm_clock_get_cycles+0x9/0x10
[562074.392673]  [] ? getnstimeofday+0x58/0xf0
[562074.394697]  [] ? do_page_fault+0x3e/0xa0
[562074.395974]  [] ? page_fault+0x25/0x30
[562074.397218] Mem-Info:
[562074.399103] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
[562074.400605] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[562074.402129] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[562074.403506] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
[562074.405629] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
[562074.406749] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
[562074.407914] Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
[562074.409325] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
[562074.410787] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
[562074.411941] active_anon:717855 inactive_anon:182000 isolated_anon:5083
[562074.411943]  active_file:32 inactive_file:192 isolated_file:64
[562074.411944]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:259 unstable:0
[562074.411944]  free:21353 slab_reclaimable:5762 slab_unreclaimable:10906
[562074.411945]  mapped:63 shmem:43 pagetables:21560 bounce:0
[562074.418218] Node 0 DMA free:15724kB min:248kB low:308kB high:372kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15312kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[562074.424382] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3512 4017 4017
[562074.426602] Node 0 DMA32 free:61060kB min:58868kB low:73584kB high:88300kB active_anon:2667432kB inactive_anon:524160kB active_file:4kB inactive_file:396kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):15980kB isolated(file):384kB present:3596500kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:560kB mapped:232kB shmem:172kB slab_reclaimable:15184kB slab_unreclaimable:17264kB kernel_stack:6736kB pagetables:66680kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:64 all_unreclaimable? no
[562074.432920] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 505 505
[562074.434773] Node 0 Normal free:8392kB min:8464kB low:10580kB high:12696kB active_anon:203604kB inactive_anon:203616kB active_file:124kB inactive_file:320kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):4992kB isolated(file):128kB present:517120kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:476kB mapped:20kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:7864kB slab_unreclaimable:26360kB kernel_stack:6832kB pagetables:19560kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:32 all_unreclaimable? no
[562074.441562] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[562074.443251] Node 0 DMA: 3*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 1*2048kB 3*4096kB = 15724kB
[562074.449972] Node 0 DMA32: 492*4kB 4530*8kB 511*16kB 140*32kB 89*64kB 3*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 60784kB
[562074.455851] Node 0 Normal: 1455*4kB 68*8kB 3*16kB 2*32kB 0*64kB 1*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 8396kB
[562074.461844] 22462 total pagecache pages
[562074.463320] 21989 pages in swap cache
[562074.464571] Swap cache stats: add 34726956, delete 34704967, find 25405257/28809084
[562074.466666] Free swap  = 0kB
[562074.467793] Total swap = 4194252kB
[562074.508867] 1048575 pages RAM
[562074.510066] 67960 pages reserved
[562074.511918] 7658 pages shared
[562074.513082] 947230 pages non-shared
[562074.514178] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
[562074.516236] [  490]     0   490     2680        0   1     -17         -1000 udevd
[562074.518561] [  790]     0   790     2662        0   1     -17         -1000 udevd
[562074.520752] [ 1342]     0  1342    62368       50   1       0             0 rsyslogd
[562074.522842] [ 1357]     0  1357     4563       23   0       0             0 irqbalance
[562074.525130] [ 1376]    25  1376    59678      129   0       0             0 named
[562074.527174] [ 1394]    81  1394     5359        1   0       0             0 dbus-daemon
[562074.529698] [ 1432]     0  1432     1020        0   0       0             0 acpid
[562074.532021] [ 1451]    28  1451   336791      177   0       0             0 nscd
[562074.534053] [ 1569]     0  1569    16086       24   1     -17         -1000 sshd
[562074.536171] [ 1580]    38  1580     6262       27   1       0             0 ntpd
[562074.539282] [ 2053]     0  2053     4662        1   0       0             0 dovecot
[562074.542072] [ 2065]   401  2065    10639        1   0       0             0 pop3-login
[562074.545036] [ 2066]   401  2066    10637        1   0       0             0 imap-login
[562074.547647] [ 2067]    97  2067     3368        1   0       0             0 anvil
[562074.550029] [ 2068]     0  2068     3401        1   1       0             0 log
[562074.552190] [ 2070]   401  2070    10655        1   0       0             0 pop3-login
[562074.554224] [ 2071]   401  2071    10670        1   0       0             0 imap-login
[562074.556886] [ 2072]     0  2072     3659        1   0       0             0 config
[562074.560112] [ 2082]    47  2082    18238        1   1       0             0 exim
[562074.562160] [ 2100]     0  2100    49742      335   1       0             0 /usr/local/cpan
[562074.564197] [ 2102]     0  2102    53119      223   0       0             0 spamd child
[562074.566209] [ 2129]     0  2129    45352        1   0       0             0 abrtd
[562074.568273] [ 2139]     0  2139    45197        1   0       0             0 abrt-dump-oops
[562074.570489] [ 2150]     0  2150    19189      124   0       0             0 httpd
[562074.572607] [ 2165]     0  2165    34191        0   0       0             0 pure-ftpd
[562074.574719] [ 2167]     0  2167    34036        1   0       0             0 pure-authd
[562074.577609] [ 2260]     0  2260    29271       27   1       0             0 crond
[562074.580212] [ 2275]     0  2275     4857        5   1       0             0 atd
[562074.582301] [ 2375]     0  2375    26952      125   0       0             0 cpsrvd (SSL) - 
[562074.584483] [ 2381]     0  2381     8172       69   0       0             0 queueprocd - wa
[562074.586500] [ 2391]     0  2391    27506       53   0       0             0 dnsadmin - serv
[562074.589509] [ 2419]     0  2419    20822      258   0       0             0 tailwatchd
[562074.592045] [ 2433]     0  2433    19586        1   0       0             0 cPhulkd - proce
[562074.594295] [ 2476]     0  2476    33028       60   0       0             0 cpdavd - accept
[562074.597210] [ 2512]     0  2512     5915      102   1       0             0 cpanellogd - sl
[562074.600503] [ 2540]     0  2540     1016        1   1       0             0 mingetty
[562074.603689] [ 2542]     0  2542     1016        1   0       0             0 mingetty
[562074.610302] [ 2545]     0  2545     1016        1   1       0             0 mingetty
[562074.615154] [ 2547]     0  2547     2679        0   0     -17         -1000 udevd
[562074.617989] [ 2548]     0  2548     1016        1   1       0             0 mingetty
[562074.622920] [ 2550]     0  2550     1016        1   1       0             0 mingetty
[562074.625853] [ 2552]     0  2552     1016        1   1       0             0 mingetty
[562074.628530] [30499]     0 30499   147473       23   0       0             0 clamd
[562074.631934] [ 8712]     0  8712     2394        1   1       0             0 mysqld_safe
[562074.634865] [ 9408]   402  9408   564397    42943   0       0             0 mysqld
[562074.637620] [24553]     0 24553    27283        1   1       0             0 sshd
[562074.641062] [24562]     0 24562    13893        1   0       0             0 sftp-server
[562074.643785] [25296]     0 25296    27283        1   1       0             0 sshd
[562074.646513] [25312]     0 25312    26649        1   0       0             0 bash
[562074.649571] [25954]    99 25954    19222       60   0       0             0 httpd
[562074.652579] [25955]     0 25955    19061        1   0       0             0 leechprotect
[562074.655407] [25958]    99 25958   334134      795   0       0             0 httpd
[562074.657912] [25959]    99 25959   334193      806   1       0             0 httpd
[562074.660551] [25960]    99 25960   334438      802   0       0             0 httpd
[562074.663110] [26044]    99 26044   334439      803   0       0             0 httpd
[562074.665618] [26206]    99 26206   334191      844   1       0             0 httpd
[562074.668698] [26361]    99 26361   334134      886   0       0             0 httpd
[562074.671241] [28324]     0 28324    27283        1   1       0             0 sshd
[562074.673759] [28333]     0 28333    26649        1   0       0             0 bash
[562074.676257] [28546]    99 28546   334167      821   0       0             0 httpd
[562074.702428] [ 1091]     0  1091    27283        1   1       0             0 sshd
[562074.704538] [ 1130]     0  1130    26649        1   0       0             0 bash
[562074.706652] [ 5276]   500  5276    77474     7801   1       0             0 php
[562074.708866] [ 5278]   500  5278    77582     7649   0       0             0 php
[562074.711662] [ 5281]   500  5281    77580     7259   1       0             0 php
[562074.714235] [ 5290]   500  5290    77601     7474   1       0             0 php
[562074.716490] [ 5295]   500  5295    77538     7540   1       0             0 php
[562074.718824] [ 5299]   500  5299    77414     7551   1       0             0 php
[562074.721384] [ 5302]   500  5302    77518     8104   1       0             0 php
[562074.724114] [ 5304]   500  5304    77414     7522   1       0             0 php
[562074.726653] [ 5308]   500  5308    77582     7241   0       0             0 php
[562074.729482] [ 5309]   500  5309    77542     7294   0       0             0 php
[562074.731758] [ 5367]   500  5367    79215     8223   0       0             0 php
[562074.734948] [ 5369]   500  5369    79230     7073   1       0             0 php
[562074.738000] [ 5389]   500  5389    74670     6863   1       0             0 php
[562074.740609] [ 5407]   500  5407    74996     5832   0       0             0 php
[562074.742809] [ 5415]   500  5415    75850     6233   1       0             0 php
[562074.745813] [ 5416]   500  5416    75061     5948   1       0             0 php
[562074.748265] [ 5418]   500  5418    74992     5796   1       0             0 php
[562074.750694] [ 5420]   500  5420    76190     7332   0       0             0 php
[562074.753004] [ 5430]   500  5430    74932     6113   1       0             0 php
[562074.755384] [ 5434]   500  5434    75460     6480   1       0             0 php
[562074.757639] [ 5439]   500  5439    74928     5879   1       0             0 php
[562074.761562] [ 5440]   500  5440    75125     5701   1       0             0 php
[562074.764306] [ 5442]   500  5442    75914     6693   1       0             0 php
[562074.766600] [ 5446]   500  5446    75214     5475   1       0             0 php
[562074.768955] [ 5448]   500  5448    74705     6309   1       0             0 php
[562074.771372] [ 5450]   500  5450    73976     6564   0       0             0 php
[562074.773778] [ 5451]   500  5451    73831     6459   1       0             0 php
[562074.776178] [ 5458]   500  5458    74611     7603   0       0             0 php
[562074.778666] [ 5459]   500  5459    75781     8240   1       0             0 php
[562074.781649] [ 5465]   500  5465    73772     7310   1       0             0 php
[562074.784412] [ 5470]   500  5470    74414     7797   1       0             0 php
[562074.788349] [ 5476]   500  5476    74864     8214   1       0             0 php
[562074.790625] [ 5480]   500  5480    73510     8366   0       0             0 php
[562074.793613] [ 5482]   500  5482    73708     8698   0       0             0 php
[562074.796689] [ 5492]   500  5492    72444    11027   1       0             0 php
[562074.799184] [ 5496]   500  5496    72784    12415   1       0             0 php
[562074.802301] [ 5499]   500  5499    73768    11388   0       0             0 php
[562074.804993] [ 5500]   500  5500    72582    11302   0       0             0 php
[562074.808597] [ 5503]   500  5503    70752     9687   0       0             0 php
[562074.810941] [ 5513]   500  5513    73447    10543   0       0             0 php
[562074.813474] [ 5519]   500  5519    72728    12005   1       0             0 php
[562074.815596] [ 5520]   500  5520    72710    11134   1       0             0 php
[562074.818435] [ 5523]   500  5523    72246    11313   0       0             0 php
[562074.821278] [ 5533]   500  5533    73576    12705   0       0             0 php
[562074.824227] [ 5536]   500  5536    70305    11674   1       0             0 php
[562074.826292] [ 5541]   500  5541    73378    13119   1       0             0 php
[562074.828638] [ 5545]   500  5545    69769    10932   1       0             0 php
[562074.831461] [ 5548]   500  5548    69382    10296   0       0             0 php
[562074.833803] [ 5549]   500  5549    73458    13978   1       0             0 php
[562074.836589] [ 5564]   500  5564    69708    11383   1       0             0 php
[562074.839962] [ 5568]   500  5568    69380    12267   0       0             0 php
[562074.842304] [ 5570]   500  5570    69580    13324   1       0             0 php
[562074.844533] [ 5574]   500  5574    69057    13993   0       0             0 php
[562074.847082] [ 5577]   500  5577    69450    13875   1       0             0 php
[562074.849309] [ 5578]   500  5578    70048    14829   1       0             0 php
[562074.851653] [ 5587]   500  5587    69514    15274   1       0             0 php
[562074.854140] [ 5589]   500  5589    69382    16196   1       0             0 php
[562074.856537] [ 5593]   500  5593    68012    14763   0       0             0 php
[562074.858820] [ 5597]   500  5597    71343    18344   0       0             0 php
[562074.861408] [ 5598]   500  5598    66115    12838   1       0             0 php
[562074.864285] [ 5603]   500  5603    69319    16732   1       0             0 php
[562074.866510] [ 5612]   500  5612    63573    11969   0       0             0 php
[562074.868753] [ 5613]   500  5613    61574     9964   1       0             0 php
[562074.871009] [ 5616]   500  5616    63637    12150   0       0             0 php
[562074.874032] [ 5624]   500  5624    63726    12707   1       0             0 php
[562074.876563] [ 5625]   500  5625    55276     4013   1       0             0 php
[562074.879156] [ 5630]   500  5630    52951     2211   0       0             0 php
[562074.881476] [ 5631]   500  5631    53736     3070   1       0             0 php
[562074.883968] [ 5633]   500  5633    53245     2474   0       0             0 php
[562074.886305] [ 5634]   500  5634    54533     3868   1       0             0 php
[562074.888585] [ 5635]   500  5635    54650     3839   0       0             0 php
[562074.890872] [ 5636]   500  5636    56802     6104   0       0             0 php
[562074.893228] [ 5637]   500  5637    54189     3375   1       0             0 php
[562074.895530] [ 5638]   500  5638    54563     3901   0       0             0 php
[562074.897784] [ 5639]   500  5639    52667     1958   1       0             0 php
[562074.900122] [ 5640]   500  5640    54533     3711   0       0             0 php
[562074.902475] [ 5641]   500  5641    52922     2197   0       0             0 php
[562074.904697] [ 5642]   500  5642    52667     1954   1       0             0 php
[562074.907013] [ 5643]   500  5643    52958     2226   0       0             0 php
[562074.909381] [ 5644]   500  5644    52667     1927   0       0             0 php
[562074.911628] [ 5645]   500  5645    54015     3402   1       0             0 php
[562074.913914] [ 5646]   500  5646    52951     2165   0       0             0 php
[562074.916614] [ 5647]   500  5647    54635     3863   1       0             0 php
[562074.919109] [ 5648]    99  5648   219408      400   1       0             0 httpd
[562074.921510] [ 5649]   500  5649    53928     3331   1       0             0 php
[562074.924011] [ 5650]   500  5650    56653     5958   0       0             0 php
[562074.926651] [ 5651]   500  5651    52951     2223   0       0             0 php
[562074.929157] [ 5652]   500  5652    52735     1997   1       0             0 php
[562074.954567] [ 5653]   500  5653    52457     1707   1       0             0 php
[562074.957251] [ 5654]    99  5654   235792      481   1       0             0 httpd
[562074.959480] [ 5660]   500  5660    53928     3321   0       0             0 php
[562074.961682] [ 5686]   500  5686    54417     3563   0       0             0 php
[562074.964573] [ 5712]   500  5712    52958     2216   0       0             0 php
[562074.966804] [ 5713]   500  5713    53887     3247   0       0             0 php
[562074.969044] [ 5714]   500  5714    52951     2206   0       0             0 php
[562074.971840] [ 5715]   500  5715    53736     3103   1       0             0 php
[562074.974827] [ 5716]   500  5716    52663     1938   1       0             0 php
[562074.977527] [ 5717]   500  5717    56118     5385   0       0             0 php
[562074.980867] [ 5726]   500  5726    57172     6396   1       0             0 php
[562074.984658] [ 5727]   500  5727    52523     1760   0       0             0 php
[562074.987267] [ 5728]   500  5728    52587     1869   1       0             0 php
[562074.989641] [ 5730]   500  5730    52430     1711   1       0             0 php
[562074.992423] [ 5731]   500  5731    53672     3061   0       0             0 php
[562074.995140] [ 5732]   500  5732    52587     1860   1       0             0 php
[562074.998136] [ 5733]   500  5733    52770     2016   0       0             0 php
[562075.002104] [ 5734]   500  5734    53216     2537   1       0             0 php
[562075.004987] [ 5735]   500  5735    54351     3615   1       0             0 php
[562075.007912] [ 5737]   500  5737    54329     3665   0       0             0 php
[562075.010646] [ 5738]   500  5738    53864     3231   1       0             0 php
[562075.013388] [ 5750]   500  5750    53992     3332   1       0             0 php
[562075.016259] [ 5751]   500  5751    53992     3356   1       0             0 php
[562075.018239] [ 5754]   500  5754    52457     1707   0       0             0 php
[562075.020361] [ 5755]   500  5755    53672     3008   0       0             0 php
[562075.022769] [ 5758]   500  5758    53928     3334   1       0             0 php
[562075.024717] [ 5759]   500  5759    53800     3153   0       0             0 php
[562075.026820] [ 5760]   500  5760    52457     1715   1       0             0 php
[562075.029743] [ 5761]   500  5761    53672     2999   1       0             0 php
[562075.031868] [ 5767]   500  5767    52430     1709   0       0             0 php
[562075.033922] [ 5768]   500  5768    53672     3015   1       0             0 php
[562075.035960] [ 5772]   500  5772    52457     1708   1       0             0 php
[562075.038017] [ 5774]   500  5774    53928     3307   0       0             0 php
[562075.040342] [ 5777]   500  5777    52430     1709   0       0             0 php
[562075.042585] [ 5780]   500  5780    52922     2200   1       0             0 php
[562075.044900] [ 5781]   500  5781    29874      419   0       0             0 php
[562075.046949] [ 5782]   500  5782    52430     1710   0       0             0 php
[562075.049163] [ 5787]   500  5787    53736     3111   0       0             0 php
[562075.051348] [ 5788]   500  5788    52428     1681   0       0             0 php
[562075.053411] [ 5789]   500  5789    16226       45   1       0             0 php
[562075.055455] [ 5790]   500  5790    53992     3361   0       0             0 php
[562075.057385] [ 5796]   500  5796    53800     3145   0       0             0 php
[562075.059354] [ 5802]   500  5802    51933     1164   0       0             0 php
[562075.061403] [ 5803]   500  5803    53736     3088   1       0             0 php
[562075.063319] [ 5828]   500  5828    52457     1712   1       0             0 php
[562075.065328] [ 5830]   500  5830    53992     3362   1       0             0 php
[562075.067304] [ 5833]   500  5833    52457     1711   0       0             0 php
[562075.069272] [ 5834]   500  5834    52457     1710   0       0             0 php
[562075.071342] [ 5838]   500  5838    25576       65   0       0             0 php
[562075.073811] [ 5839]    99  5839   121104      248   1       0             0 httpd
[562075.075876] [ 5848]    99  5848   121104      279   1       0             0 httpd
[562075.078224] [ 5849]   500  5849    29230      282   1       0             0 php
[562075.080532] [ 5850]   500  5850    29118      217   1       0             0 php
[562075.082861] [ 5851]   500  5851    53352     2643   0       0             0 php
[562075.084933] [ 5852]    99  5852   121104      281   1       0             0 httpd
[562075.087091] [ 5854]   500  5854    52430     1708   0       0             0 php
[562075.089180] [ 5856]   500  5856    51703      882   0       0             0 php
[562075.091154] [ 5863]    99  5863   121104      286   1       0             0 httpd
[562075.093112] [ 5970]   500  5970    28797      186   1       0             0 php
[562075.095140] [ 5986]     0  5986     5651       60   0       0             0 upcp-running
[562075.097396] [ 5988]   500  5988    29118      223   0       0             0 php
[562075.099621] [ 5991]    99  5991   104720      241   0       0             0 httpd
[562075.101929] [ 5993]   500  5993     3116       43   0       0             0 suphp
[562075.104055] [ 5994]   500  5994    29329      408   0       0             0 php
[562075.106361] [ 6026]   500  6026    29118      223   0       0             0 php
[562075.108660] [ 6027]   500  6027    29118      231   1       0             0 php
[562075.111327] [ 6028]   500  6028     7365       23   1       0             0 php
[562075.113563] [ 6032]    99  6032   121104      279   1       0             0 httpd
[562075.115682] Out of memory: Kill process 9408 (mysqld) score 44 or sacrifice child
[562075.117786] Killed process 9408, UID 402, (mysqld) total-vm:2257588kB, anon-rss:171860kB, file-rss:544kB
```

This occurs only once or twice in the day. Otherwise the load is well within limits (<2.00). The load reaches >100 when this error occurs. As per the access logs I wasn't getting more traffic when this happened. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: The question and subject are not connected

Answer (score 4):

> What should I do to fix this?

Add memory or reduce the load on memory from processes.

---

Install monitoring

Gather data.

Use [Scientific Method](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876) to work out where the bottlenecks are.

Take appropriate action.

Repeat as required.