# Centos Network issue Up/Down randomly on Bridge

Tags: networking, centos, linux-networking, centos7

I have physic server on CentOS 7, with LXC container and bridget network.
Also 3 IP address:

`*.202: on bridget network of host`

`*.213: on bridget network of first big LXC`

`*.214: on bridget network of second big LXC`

*.202 up/down randomly, no configuration change, it's just start to up/down from some moment.

Serverdensity monitoring detected loss on main IP this night, at:

1:02 - 1-5 min downtime

4:39 - 1-5 min downtime

7:10 - 1-5 min downtime

7:42 - 1-5 min downtime

8:48 - 1-5 min downtime

Time is GMT+3

No loss on second and third IP, it worked normaly.

And this time is the same as monitorix reported from this host, localy:
[monitorix graph](https://habrastorage.org/files/e7d/cf3/291/e7dcf3291cf94f2a927458b3e83e4f04.png)

route -n from host:

```
    route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         88.198.61.193   0.0.0.0         UG    425    0        0 bridge0
    10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
    10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
    10.20.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr2
    88.198.61.192   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     425    0        0 bridge0
    192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr1
```

route -n from *.213

```
    route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         88.198.61.193   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
    88.198.61.192   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1035   0        0 eth0
```

brctl from host:

```
    bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
    bridge0     8000.32a853223b87   no      enp4s0
                                            vnet1
                                            vnet2
    virbr1      8000.169641375908   yes     virbr1-nic
                                            vnet0
                                            vnet4
                                            vnet5
                                            vnet6
                                            vnet7
                                            vnet8
    virbr2      8000.226f586158a8   yes     virbr2-nic
                                            vnet3
                                            vnet9
```

`*.202 is on: bridge0 (down some time)`

`*.213 is on: vnet1 (work well)`

`*.214 is on: vnet2 (work well)`

ifconfig and netstat from host: http://paste.ubuntu.com/22669410/

How to find the source of the problem?
Could this be the problem CentOS installation or configuration?

Answer (score 1):

> How to find the source of the problem?

Check all of your logs for relevant entries

Use [Scientific Method](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876) to help you track down the problem.

... the usual stuff really.

Comment: What's logs will be useful?