# Godaddy dedicated server randomly timeout users on just 400-500 Active users

Tags: windows, mysql

We have Godaddy's Dedicated server. but we are facing problems with this server. after on 400-500 active users server randomly timeout or kill users. we this it's error with IIS. We did conversation with some server experts they said there is some issue with IIS. but nobody can resolve this issue. i share a screen shoot of analytic of active users. Please help us.[analytic report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlJgZ.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBYuD.png)

Comment: In the future please use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" rather than posting screenshots. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. - Also rather than the "friendly" error messages web apps display to visitors take a look if your logs display more details, although if the pool is too small increasing it might be the obvious solution.

Answer (score 3):

Install monitoring then repeat as necessary

- Gather data
- Analyse data
- Make changes based on analysis
- Monitor effect of changes

This isn't rocket science but there's no reason why you can't use [Scientific Method](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876).

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the code given out in the error message and think if it could exhaust server resources in some way and then either fix the code or postpone problems by adding resources to the server.