# How to identify the bottlenecks in a Debian/Ubuntu nginx + php5-fpm setup

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I would like any hints or ideas as to what might be causing the following situation.

The website is on a Debian server with nginx 1.6.2, php5 through fpm.

A GET request to a page is supposed to generate a ZIP archive of considerable size from a few requested files that are on the server. It's a resource demanding operation, taking about 30 seconds (let's say) and consuming ~500+MiB of memory.

Now if during that operation the client attempts to open another page, the PHP's session handling will impose a delay for that page to open until the first GET request is finished. All this is within my understanding up until now.

However: if the client (insistently) refreshes the browser several times (5-8) the server will not respond at all to ANY user, not just the insistent one. This bugs me because the nginx configuration is set to 2 `worker_processes`, each with 1024 `worker_connections`, which should give me at least about 1000 connections before the server goes bunkers.

Top command reveals little CPU load.

Enlighten, please.

Comment: have you set "pm_max_children" in the php pool.d config?

Comment: "WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it" looks like we're on the right track @Orphans

Comment: Looks for pm.max_children in /etc/php5/pool.d/www.conf and change it to a higher value

Comment: Yes, already addressed this. Please make this into a response - I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like PHP is running out of children. In your case - try edit:

```
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Look for `pm.max_children = 5` and change it to a higher value (10 or more)

You could also check for `php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M`
(max allow memoryconsumption allow for each child)

Remove the comment and change the value to something that suites you setup.

Answer (score 0):

<Stuck record>

You need to be scientific and methodical in your approach to this. In particular [Scientific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) [Method](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876) is your friend.

- Install monitoring
- Gather data
- Analyse data
- Make changes based on analysis
- Monitor changes
- Document

Rinse and repeat as necessary

</Stuck record>

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is the CPU is exhausted. Have you used "top" to work it out?

Nginx lets you impose rate limits with the [rate limit module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html). There's a tutorial on how to do this [here](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/), but it's more at the resource level than the IP level, I think. This block should limit requests and connections, which would be more appropriate for you - code from [this site](https://www.axivo.com/threads/limit-nginx-connections-per-ip.97/).

```
http {
  ...
  limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=alpha:8m;
  limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr zone=delta:8m rate=30r/s;
  ...

  server {
    ...
    limit_conn alpha 5;
    limit_req  zone=delta burst=80 nodelay;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that CPU stands quietly under 40%. Also from my experience it's never the CPU - something else gives up first. I'll add the top output to my question.