# How to reduce server response time for a magento e-commerce site

Tags: magento

We have an e-commerce site developed using magento 1.9.0.1, we could not able to reduce server response time to below one sec, (as per google page speed testing tool we have now 1.4 sec) we have tried almost all optimization process as below

1 - Using magento full page cache from well reputed company

2 - Added gzip compression

3 - Using cloudflare as CDN

4 - tried magento flat catalog table and disable unwanted indexes and make it indexing manually.

Server and traffic details

Location - UK

Sessions/M: 17929

Unique users/M - 14860

Page views/M - 58323

Bandwidth usage/Month - 61.09 GB

Total processors: 8

Processor #1 x 8

Vendor

GenuineIntel

Name
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 0 @ 2.00GHz

Speed
2000.050 MHz

Cache
20480 KB

RAM - 8 GB

Current Memory Usage

```
          total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:       8027740    7674716     353024      26052     928848    2992492
-/+ buffers/cache:    3753376    4274364
Swap:      1048572     210260     838312
Total:     9076312    7884976    1191336
```

Operating system Linux

Mysql Database size - 3782 MB

we have more than 40K SKUs

We have similar site running in USA with different name and its server response time is good, but it has less traffic.

Can anyone help/suggest some solution to reduce server response time?

Thanks
Prajosh

Comment: something is fundamentally wrong with your site / server. Turn off your theme and go back to the default.. does that help? If not start to turn off your extensions 1 by 1 till  you fine the culprit. If you have low traffic that processor is not the best choice and it would be worth swapping to a higher clocked e3 rather than a low clocked e5.  However, that is a minor thing.  A normal magneto site should be showing around 0.2 - 0.3 server response time.  Also.. check your network card with ethtool.. is it showing the correct values or any errors?

Answer (score 3):

If you have not already done so, you should install monitoring, gather data, and apply [Scientific Method.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method).

You need to spend time looking at your system, understand how it is performing and relate that to what is happening in your application.

How are your processors faring ? Is the system load high? What's causing that?

Do you you have high I/O Wait values? Why?

Are your queries optimised ? Do you have proper indexing ? Have you checked for long running queries ?

...

[Further](https://serverfault.com/questions/646852/excessive-number-of-sleeping-processes-in-centos-howto-diagnose/646876#646876) [reading](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A9517%20scientific%20method)

Answer (score 0):

did you tried not to use apache but nginx? [image: general example comparison]

it also uses a lot less RAM
[image: ram usage]

and can handle more requests
[image: requests]

Comment: switching from Apache httpd to Nginx might be the right thing to do once you have fully analysed the situation and made that decision but until you have done that answers like this seem more religious than scientific.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably PHP limited. In that case nginx won't help.
You  can use Varnish in combination with the [Turpentine](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/turpentine-varnish-cache.html) addon to make catalog pages a lot faster. That solves 90% of your load. Checkout will still be slow though.